# Error placement on top of select tag for Jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

[image]

Started using jquery validation, unable to place the error after the select tag for all other it is placing after the field for only select tag its working like that. How to fix it.

javascript:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('#issue_form').validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'desc',
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
      "issue[item]":{
        required: true
      },
      "issue[odometer_reading]":{
        required: true
      },
      "issue[vehicle_id]":{
        required: true
      }
    },

    messages: {
      "issue[vehicle_id]": { 
        required: "Vehicle Selection is required"
      },
      "issue[item]": { 
        required: "This Field is required"
      },
      "issue[odometer_reading]": { 
        required: "Odometer Reading is required"
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.col-sm-8').removeClass('success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.col-sm-8').removeClass('has-error')
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      var elem = $(element);
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }  })
<script>
```

My HTML Code which is actually embedded ruby code, form.select will be select as in HTML

```
<%= form_with(model: issue, local: true,id:"issue_form") do |form| %>

  <div class = "form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class=" col-sm-3 control-label" for="textInput2-modal-markup">Vehicle</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.select :vehicle_id, Vehicle.all.pluck( :registration_num, :id),{prompt: "Nothing Selected"},{class:"inspect_vehicle",id:"issue_vehicle_id"}%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textInput-modal-markup">Issue</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.text_field :item ,class:"form-control"%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
      <p style="float:right;">
        <%= form.submit "Save",class:"btn btn-primary" %>
      </p>
    </hr>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Post your `html` code also.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal posted my HTML code

Answer (score 0):

adding error class after select2-container class resolved my issue